# Remove link if contains specific string

Tags: php, str-replace, strpos

I have this PHP code where a specific word is converted to link before sending in email.

```
$message = str_replace(
           'hello',
           '<a id="get-ahead-link" style="color: #ffa503;" href="https://somelink.com"> hello </a>',
           $message,
           $count);
```

The code above is completely working but I got an issue when a link with the word 'hello' is already included.

Example:

> hello world. Please visit my site: http://helloworld.com.

This becomes:

> [hello](https://somelink.com) world. Please visit my site: http://[hello](https://somelink.com)world.com.

But what I need:

> [hello](https://somelink.com) world. Please visit my site: http://helloworld.com.

Is this possible? What am I missing with my work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`preg_replace`](http://www.php.net/preg_replace) (replacement using regular expressions) and surround your string with `(?<=^|\s)` ("is either at the beginning of the string or preceded by a space character") and [`\b` (word boundaries)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
$message = preg_replace(
  '/(?<=^|\s)hello\b/', 
  '<a id="get-ahead-link" style="color: #ffa503;" href="https://somelink.com">hello</a>', 
  $message, 
  -1, 
  $count
);
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/SknUT**

Note: I left the additional parameters to retrieve `$count`.

Other (unrelated) note: such inline HTML styles should be avoided in most cases.

Comment: Thanks @Jeto! What's the use of -1?

Comment: @jeepers_creepers -1 is the limit, it's one of `preg_replace`'s parameters (refer to the manual for more info). Actually, this solution isn't working in some cases, let me edit the answer (give me a few minutes).

Comment: @jeepers_creepers There you go, edited. I've assumed you didn't want any replacement if the string contained "hellooooooo!" or something like that, it has to be the exact word "hello". Otherwise, just remove the `\b` from the regular expression.

Comment: it's working! I deleted my comment because of my typo. I tried. `hello.` and `http://hello.com`

Comment: No problem, deleted mine too. Happy it helped.